# how to keep the width of the child title in the drop down same as parent?

Tags: html, css

I would like to keep the width of the drop down contents same as the parent but I am failing to so since some of the child titles are longer in length compared to the parent. what should I do about the longer titles in the drop down menu?

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background: #2f3036;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover a {
  background: #97455f;
}

li:hover ul a {
  background: grey;
  color: #2f3036;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

li:hover ul a:hover {
  background: #97455f;
  color: #fff;
}

li ul {
  display: none;
}

li ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}

.hidden {
  padding: 0;
}

ul li a:hover+.hidden,
.hidden:hover {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 460px) {
  ul {
    position: static;
    display: none;
  }
  li {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
  }
  ul li,
  li a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .show-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Somthing</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">something</a>
    <ul class="hidden">
      <li><a href="#">somethoingaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to hide the overflowing text? If so adding to your .hidden rules overflow: hidden; and width: 100%; (remove the width: auto; from the hover rules) and adding to your li rules position: relative; seems to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You may break the word in multiple lines setting [`word-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) to [`break-word`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap#Values).

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background: #2f3036;
  text-decoration: none;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

li:hover a {
  background: #97455f;
}

li:hover ul a {
  background: grey;
  color: #2f3036;
  min-height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

li:hover ul a:hover {
  background: #97455f;
  color: #fff;
}

li ul {
  display: none;
}

li ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}

.hidden {
  padding: 0;
}

ul li a:hover+.hidden,
.hidden:hover {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 460px) {
  ul {
    position: static;
    display: none;
  }
  li {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
  }
  ul li,
  li a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .show-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Somthing</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">something</a>
    <ul class="hidden">
      <li><a class href="#">somethoingaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a></li>
      <li><a class href="#">something</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```